# Case and accent insensitive sorting of MySQL JSON string

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL table `my_table` with JSON values like this:

```
id | data
---+--------------------
1  | {"name": "à l'avenir"}
2  | {"name": "je veux"}
3  | {"name": "Que ça marche"}
```

I use this query to sort by name asc:

```
SELECT `data`->>'$.name' AS `name` FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

and I get items in this order:

```
Que ça marche
je veux
à l'avenir
```

Is there a way to get the results as if it was collated with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ?

Strings in MySQL JSON fields are collated as `utf8mb4_bin`, which is case and accent sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to explicitly specify the `COLLATE` used:

```sql
SELECT `data` ->> '$.name' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci `name`
FROM `my_table`
ORDER BY `name` ASC;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1d28f5a2cb11180107d70518a5fda39).